# Best way to make sure a folder isn't processed more than once

Tags: powershell

Part of our backup environment has 4 copies of the same data accessible from one computer with paths similar to this:
`J:\Digital Library\`
`L:\Digital Library\`
`\\OnSiteServer\Collections\Digital Library\`
`\\OffSiteServer\Collections\Digital Library\`

I started writing a function to do work on these copies with the intent of receiving the paths from the pipeline, but it occurred to me: "What happens if the same path is entered more than once?"

**An absurd example would be:**

```
Set-Location -Path 'L:\'
"\\OnSiteServer\Collections\Digital Library",
"\\OnSiteServer\Collections\Digital Library\",
'L:\Digital Library\',
  '\Digital Library\',
   'Digital Library\',
'L:\Digital Library' ,
  '\Digital Library' ,
   'Digital Library' | Find-BadCreationTimes
```

In the best case scenario, you will be wasting a lot of time and probably creating multiple reports of the same drive.  In the worst case, the script was supposed to make changes to the contents of each path and each pass made even more changes.

I thought I solved the issue by running each path through this command and using a HashSet to verify if the folder has been processed.

```
$NormalizedPath = Join-Path (Resolve-Path $Path).ProviderPath ''
```

But then I realized that we have weird situations where a subfolder down inside a share also has its own share, making the data in that subfolder accessible from 2 entirely different paths.

So now I'm thinking I need to save a text file with a random GUID in each folder.

Are there better alternatives?

Comment: The $5 word here is "idempotent".

Comment: Sounds like you could use the `Root` property from the PSDrive objects assuming `L:` and `J:` are PSDrives

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, thank you, `Root` is a possibility.  Concerning network shares, I'm wondering about mimicking what a person might do if looking at the contents of 2 shares to see if they are the same. I'm noticing that the LastAccessTime is never the same on anything in any of the drives.  Perhaps run something like this on both paths and compare the results: `(Get-ChildItem $Path -Force | Sort-Object -Property Name | Foreach-Object {'{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}' -f $(if($_.PSIsContainer){'C'}else{'L'}), $_.Mode, $_.Name, $_.CreationTime, $_.LastAccessTime, $_.LastWriteTime}) -join ''`

Answer (score 0):

In the case you mention where a server has shared files multiple times, like so:

```
ShareName LocalPath   Description
----      ----        -----------
Foo       D:\Foo      Foo
Bar       D:\Foo\Bar  Bar (subdirectory)
```

Then remote clients like powershell do **not** have any way to tell remotely that `\\Server\Foo\Bar\MyFile` and `\\Server\Bar\MyFile` refer to the same item. The only way to solve that is to understand the structure of your file shares before copying stuff

If the remote share is on a windows server and you have permissions, then you can probably use the default admin root shares like `\\Server\C$\`, which are at the top level and not under some other share name.

---

To answer *"What happens if the same path is entered more than once?"*: Same as if you ran the entire function more than once, right? Garbage in = garbage out

If you expect duplicates due to relative paths, then yeah just resolve them to full paths first, and do each only once like  `| Resolve-Path | Select-Object -Property Path -Unique | ...`